# Firebase authentication - prevent users login one account same time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I have used method Firebase.authWithPassword(email, password, ...) to authentication a users. Problem is when an user has logged in, how to prevent an orther login with this account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have a /users/ node that has other information about the user

```
users
  uid
   name: Bill
   fav_foot: Pizza
   online: true
```

Note I added the online child node that is set when the user goes online (authenticates)

Attach a onDisconnect to it and either remove the node when the user disconnects or set it to false.

The reverse is true as well, when the user tries to log in, check the online node and if true, well, deny access.

Comment: Ok, i got it. I think firebase should provide this options: just one user login at time

Comment: Fortunately it's all of about 8 lines of code so it's not too hard to implement. If you like the answer, please approve it! :-)

Comment: @Jay can u pls help me how to implement this i mean when will i set online to true and when it will be false ?

Comment: @Khang.NT pls tell

Comment: @Erum Please see [Offline Capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works) and down in the How onDisconnect Works section. Simply put, when the user logs in, set the online node to :true. Then add a onDisconnect function to that node to set it to false when they disconnect. That's about it.